# Swift app crashes on real device but works on simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

This function gets the date from yesterday; it is working on my emulator but it crashes with my real device.

I am working with Xcode6 Beta 6.

```
var tuple :(value Int, unit:NSCalendarUnit) = (1, NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay)
var date = NSDate()
var yesterday = NSCalendar.currentCalender().dateByAddingUnit(tuple.unit, value: (-tuple.value), toDate: date, options: NSCalendarOptions.SearchBackwards)
```

This is the error I get on my real device:

```
-[_NSCopyOnWriteCalendarWrapper dateByAddingUnit:value:toDate:options:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x176cca10
```

Comment: which os version your device have?

Comment: I'd recommend updating to the latest beta (7) of Xcode and ensuring that your device is also on the latest iOS8 beta. There have been lots of changes in each new beta so not having the latest could cause problems.

Comment: When I run this code it has errors to begin with. http://swiftstub.com/259423818/

Comment: Please post the *actual* working code—there's no way this would even compile (you've spelt "currentCalendar" wrong, for a start.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recently had a similar error.

I suspect you're trying to run the code on a pre 8.0 device. If that's the case, `dateByAddingUnit` is not available on your device (see the header)

```
@availability(iOS, introduced=8.0)
```

You can achieve what you're trying to do by using `dateByAddingComponents' - it's a little more cumbersome but should give you the same result. Try the following playground

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

var tuple:( Int, NSCalendarUnit) = (1, NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay)

var date = NSDate()

/* 8.0+ */
var yesterday = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(tuple.1, value: (-tuple.0), toDate: date, options: NSCalendarOptions.SearchBackwards)

/* 7.1 + */

let component = NSDateComponents()

if tuple.1 == NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay {
 component.day = -tuple.0
}

var alsoYesterday = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingComponents(component, toDate: date, options: NSCalendarOptions.SearchBackwards)
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

When I ran your code it has syntax errors to begin with. I just took the following code and ran it both on a device in playground, in a online simulator and an xcode project and it works for all three.

The following works for me.

http://swiftstub.com/992344166/  Click Run to see result.

```
var date = NSDate()
var yesterday = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay, value: -1, toDate: date, options: NSCalendarOptions.SearchBackwards)
println(yesterday)
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try below code

```
let today = NSDate()
let yesterday = today.dateByAddingTimeInterval(-24 * 60 * 60)
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account daylight savings time or leap seconds and could lead to unexpected issues.