# Xcode - NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: ios, nscalendar, unrecognized-selector

My app seems to work fine in the simulator but on a real device it crashes. I catched the error and the following is displayed:

> "NSInvalidArgumentException reason - [NSCopyOnWriteCalendarWrapperdateByAddingUnit:value:toDate:options:] Unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Code loaded on view load:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //initialize gestures for swipes
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                           initWithTarget:self
                                           action:@selector(swipeRecognized:)];
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                            initWithTarget:self
                                            action:@selector(swipeRecognized:)];
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];

    // set Date to current Date
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"d-M-yyyy"];
    Date = [NSDate date];
    dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:Date];

    //retrieve data from database
    [self retrieveData];
    [self retrieveData2];
}
```

The code that generates the error below.
When users swipes to the left, the value of the date changes and new data will be retrieved by methods retrieveData & retrieveData2.

```
-(void)swipeRecognized:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipe
{
    if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {
        @try {
            //create calendar
            NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
            //Add a day to the current day
            NSDate *someDate = [cal dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay value:1 toDate:Date options:0];
            //Date has been changed so need to set Date again
            Date = someDate;

            //Format the datestring so we can pass it to Database
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"d-M-yyyy"];
            dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:Date];

            //retrieve data again because date changed
            [self retrieveData];
            [self retrieveData2];
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"catching %@ reason %@", [exception name], [exception reason]]
                                                           delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure why it's working fine in the simulator but not on the real device, I suppose it has something to do with adding the values to the date?

Kind Regards

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: This only available in iOS8, what version of iOS is on the device? It is possible you have a higher iOS on the simulator than on your device. - https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/dateByAddingUnit:value:toDate:options:

Comment: Check out this answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25722200/swift-app-crashes-on-real-device-but-works-on-simulator

Comment: Thanks Matt & William Smith! The dateByAddingUnit is not available for IOS 7 and below and was causing the crash. For lower IOS versions dateByAddingComponents needs to be used.